# como obtengo el valor de un de un Label que se encuentra en una clase desde una función externa?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

> hola! edite la mayor parte para dar un código ejecutable y entendible.
> Tengo el siguiente código:

```py
    from tkinter import * 
    
    class Tienda:
    
        def __init__(self,ventana):
            self.ventana=ventana
            self.ventana.title("Mi Tiendita") 
    
            #Marco de ventana
            marco=LabelFrame(self.ventana,text="Ingresar Producto")    
            marco.grid(columns=2,pady=10,padx=10,columnspan=4) 
    
            #Nombre
            Label(marco,text="Nombre").grid(row=0,column=0) 
            self.Nombre=Entry(marco)
            self.Nombre.grid(row=0,column=1) 
            self.Nombre.focus() 
    
            #marco2
            marco2=LabelFrame(self.ventana)    
            marco2.grid(column=0,columnspan=4)
    
            #BotonGuardar
            self.guardar=Button(marco2,text="Guardar Datos",command=self.agregarRegistro) 
            self.guardar.grid(row=2,column=0)
    
        def agregarRegistro(self):
            contenido = self.Nombre.get()
            print(contenido)
    
    if __name__=="__main__":
        ventana=Tk() 
        aplicacion=Tienda(ventana)
        ventana.mainloop()
```

> Básicamente lo que yo quiero hacer es sacar la función agregarRegistro
> de adentro de la clase. He intentado varias cosas pero no logro
> hacerlo funcionar ya que al sacarla de la clase pierdo el uso de self.
> alguien que me oriente de como reemplazar el self para poder ejecutar
> la función desde fuera de la clase?

Comment: Las clases no son objetos únicos, son "plantillas" que permiten crear objetos (Llamados instancias de la clase). Lo que haces con `cuadro = Cuadro_ingresos()` es crear una instancia de la clase y esa instancia (Nuevo elemento) se llama `cuadro`. [Lectura recomendada](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/classes.html#:~:text=Las%20clases%20de%20Python%20proveen,clase%20base%20con%20el%20mismo)

Comment: @HeytalePazguato ya entendí ese aspecto pero aun así no se como obtener datos de una instancia especifica de una clase.

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato listo ahora edite el post y se entiende mas lo que quiero realizar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si entendi bien tu duda es sobre como ejecutar el metodo agregarRegistro de tu instancia guardada en aplicacion.

Asumiendo que no sabes programacion orientada a objetos de python, te hago una breve explicacion de como acceder al contenido de una clase

### NOMENCLATURA DEL PUNTO

Para esto tu debes recurrir a la nomenclatura del punto, por ejemplo:

```
Tienda.agregarRegistro()
```

Lo cual tiene la estructura

**Clase.metodo()**

Esto se puede realizar con cualquier variable o funcion que pertenezca a una clase
una variable que pertenece a una clase se denomina ATRIBUTO
una funcion que pertenece a una clase se denomina METODO
entonces recordando estas dos definiciones te explico como acceder a tus metodos por ejemplo:
si quieres llamar a un metodo de una clase usas

**nombre_de_tu_clase.nombre_del_metodo()**

!! Recuerda agregar los parentesis o de otra forma no se ejecutara el metodo

Para acceder a una variable que pertenece a una clase es lo mismo pero con el nombre de la variable

**nombre_de_tu_clase.nombre_de_tu_atributo**

!! Recuerda que para acceder a una variable NO debes usar los parentesis, de otra forma python interpretara el nombre como el de una funcion y te devolvera error si no existe, o un metodo. !!

---

### NOMENCLATURA DEL PUNTO APLICADA A TU CLASE

Esta nomenclatura del punto aplicada a tu clase seria por ejemplo.

para acceder al atributo marco

```
Tienda.marco
```

para acceder al atributo marco2

```
Tienda.marco2
```

para acceder al atributo guardar

```
Tienda.guardar
```

para acceder al metodo agregarRegistro

```
Tienda.agregarRegistro()
```

Entonces tu puedes acceder a todo atributo o metodo contenido en tu clase por medio de la nomenclatura del punto.

Para acceder a atributos que se encuentra en el constructor( el constructor es el metodo que se llama **init** ) simplemente usas el nombre del atributo, pero para acceder atributos o metodos que no estan en el constructor si no que estan contenidos en un metodo de la clase, debes recurrir primero al metodo y despues al atributo.
por ejemplo

para acceder al atributo contenido debes hacer lo siguiente

```
Tienda.accederRegistro().contenido
```

esto es debido a que el atributo "contenido" solo se encuentra en el interior del metodo accederRegistro y no en su constructor.

Finalmente. ¿Como acceder al metodo accederRegistro ?

pues a traves de `Tienda.accederRegistro()`

---

### ACCEDIENTO A accederRegistro DE TU INSTANCIA

Pero si tu quieres acceder al metodo accederRegistro de una INSTANCIA de tu clase, en vez de usar el nombre de tu clase, deberas usar el nombre de la variable que contiene tu INSTANCIA. en tu caso, la instancia de Tienda la guardaste en la variable aplicacion, por lo que si tu quieres recurrir al metodo y atributos de tu instancia contenida en aplicacion, deberas usar la nomenclatura del punto para acceder partiendo de la variable que contiene tu instancia.
por ejemplo.

para acceder al metodo accederRegistro de la instancia contenida en aplicacion es lo siguiente

```
aplicacion.accederRegistro()
```

recordando usar los corchetes para especificar que es un metodo.

Posterior al acceder al metodo, puedes usar inmediatamente el retorno del metodo o guardarlo en una variable

uso inmediato
aqui, yo imprimo el retorno del metodo de la instancia aplicacion

```
print(aplicacion.accederRegistro())
```

guardar retorno

```
retorno_de_acceder_registro = aplicacion.accederRegistro()
```

Aclaracion, el acceder a los metodos y atributos de una instancia solo se puede realizar de forma posterior a esta ser creada, por lo que estas sentencias que te indico deberian ir de forma posterior al if__main__

La respuesta completa es:

```
from tkinter import * 

class Tienda:

    def __init__(self,ventana):
        self.ventana=ventana
        self.ventana.title("Mi Tiendita") 

        #Marco de ventana
        marco=LabelFrame(self.ventana,text="Ingresar Producto")    
        marco.grid(columns=2,pady=10,padx=10,columnspan=4) 

        #Nombre
        Label(marco,text="Nombre").grid(row=0,column=0) 
        self.Nombre=Entry(marco)
        self.Nombre.grid(row=0,column=1) 
        self.Nombre.focus() 

        #marco2
        marco2=LabelFrame(self.ventana)    
        marco2.grid(column=0,columnspan=4)

        #BotonGuardar
        self.guardar=Button(marco2,text="Guardar Datos",command=self.agregarRegistro) 
        self.guardar.grid(row=2,column=0)

    def agregarRegistro(self):
        contenido = self.Nombre.get()
        print(contenido)

if __name__=="__main__":
    ventana=Tk() 
    aplicacion=Tienda(ventana)
    ventana.mainloop() 

###############     ### SOLO ESTO AGREGUE #################
### acceder al metodo accederRegistro de la instancia de Tienda
    retorno_de_acceder_registro_de_instancia = aplicacion.accederRegistro()  
### acceder al metodo accederRegistro de la clase
    retorno_de_acceder_registro_de_clase = Tienda.accederRegistro()
```

DE ESTA FORMA, TU PUEDES ACCEDER A UN METODO DE UNA INSTANCIA O CLASE FUERA DE LA DEFINICION DE LA MISMA

Comment: Muchas gracias me costo mucho trabajo entenderlo por algún motivo las clases no me entran bien y se me dificultan pero me quedo bastante claro y logra solucionarlo gracias a tu hermosa y especifica respuesta. Se agradece el tiempo que tomaste en realizar tan perfecta aclaración.